# Flex loads SWF as Sprite. How do I load it as a Movieclip instead?

Tags: apache-flex, casting, movieclip, swfloader

I have a problem converting SWFLoader.content into a MovieClip instance while following ([TheFlashCanon's excellent tutorial](http://flash.fincanon.com/archives/category/flex)) on making a SWF communicate with Flex. The SWF loaded in question is compiled using Flash CS3 (using actionscript 3).

However, when I try to get the content of the SWFLoader and convert it into a MovieClip instance, I always get this error:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion
>   failed: cannot convert
>   maix::main_maix@49f94ec1 to
>   flash.display.MovieClip.  at
>   test1/onLoadMinigameComplete()[/Users/chiyin/Documents/Flex
>   Builder
>   3/SimpleGirlfriend/src/Main.as:68]

where maix::main_maix@49f94ec1 is an instance of my movie.

What am I doing wrong? The loaded swf plays fine otherwise, and is not denoted as a AVM1Movie.

Update: Found out that the SWF is imported as a Sprite instead of a Movieclip. How do I force the SWFLoader to load the SWF as a Movieclip instead of a Sprite object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main_maix` looks to be the document class of the swf being loaded in. If so, main_maix should extend `MovieClip` instead of `Sprite`:

```
public class main_maix extends MovieClip
```

Also, you can always cast classes an object to be able to access it freely (but not a very good practice). You may want to just "cast it as main_maix":

```
/**
 * Loader finished loading
 * 
 * @param Event Complete event
 * @return void
 */
private function onLoadMinigameComplete(event:Event):void 
{
    // -- either will allow "free access" to methods of main_maix
    var maixAsObject:Object = Object(loader.content);
    var maixAsMaix:main_maix = main_maix(loader.content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the same for dynamically loaded swfs.  But if you're making a movieclip in the Flash Authoring environment, and it only has a single frame.  Then you embed that into a Flex application.  It will embed as a sprite instead of a Movieclip.